# overlapping segments R

Tags: r, dataframe, segments

there is a data frame with which I am working it looks like this

the two columns denote start and end of a chunk. I need to know how many of these chunks are present at every position from 0 to 23110906. Sometimes the chunks overlap and sometimes there might be a region which has no chunk covering at all. It is like segments in R. but I dont need a visualisation I just need a way to find quickly the number of chunks at every postion. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Do you really want to know the count at *every* position -- all 23,110,906 positions? Or just at a any particular position of your choosing?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some data

```
m = matrix(c(10, 20, 25, 30), 2)
```

An [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) notion is `coverage()`

```
> cvg = coverage(IRanges(start=m[,1], end=m[,2]))
> cvg
integer-Rle of length 30 with 4 runs
  Lengths:  9 10  6  5
  Values :  0  1  2  1
```

Which is a compact run-length encoding; query at the ith location

```
> cvg[22]
integer-Rle of length 1 with 1 run
  Lengths: 1
  Values : 2
> runValue(cvg[22])
[1] 2
```

Do math on the Rle

```
> cvg > 1
logical-Rle of length 30 with 3 runs
  Lengths:    19     6     5
  Values : FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

or coerce to an integer vector

```
> as(cvg, "integer")
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
```

This

```
> cumsum(tabulate(m[,1], 30)) - cumsum(tabulate(m[,2], 30))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

will also be reasonably fast.

Note subtle differences between these, from differences in the notion of whether the ends are included (IRanges: yes; tabulate: no) in the range. If these are actually genome coordinates then [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) is the place to go, to account for seqname (chromosome) and strand.

Answer (score 3):

The data structure you are looking for is called [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), which is a type of sorted binary tree that contains (guess what) intervals, each of which usually has start and end positions.

I never used an interval tree to store points as you need, but I guess you can define your intervals as `interval.start = interval.end`.

Building the tree will take linear time and querying the intervals of your data frame will take logarithmic time, which is much faster than pteetor's quadratic time approach.

The R package [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) from Bioconductor may help you. I would try the function `findOverlaps()` and then `table()` the results. I invite you to read the documentation to see whether it fits your specific needs.

Comment: is there some [package implementing the interval tree and how would i use it on the data?

Answer (score 1):

I took that matrix and examined the overlaps, of which there were only five intervals with any overlaps and none with 2, assuming they were ordered by their starting postions:

```
> sum( mat[1:28,2] > mat[2:29,1] )
[1] 5
> sum( mat[1:27,2] > mat[3:29,1] )
[1] 0
```

So which ones were they?

```
> which( mat[1:28,2] > mat[2:29,1] )
[1] 19 21 23 25 28
```

So it seemed rather wasteful of machine resources and time to create a vector that was 23 million items long and it would be a lot easier to simply build a function that would count the number of intervals in which any particular position was within:

```
 fchunk <- function(pos) {sum( mat[ , 1] <= pos & mat[,2] >= pos)}
#--------
> fchunk(16675330)
[1] 2
> fchunk(16675329)
[1] 1
```

These are the intervals where there are 2:

```
sapply( which( mat[1:28,2] > mat[2:29,1] ) , 
       function(int1) c( mat[int1+1, 1], mat[int1, 2] ) )
#--------
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
n7 16675330 18097680 20233612 21288777 22847516
n8 16724700 18445265 20741145 22780817 22967567
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the count at every position -- all 23,110,906 positions -- this code will tell you.

```
countChunks = function(i) sum(dfrm$n7 <= i & i <= dfrm$n8)
counts = sapply(1:23110906, countChunks)
```

But it's very slow. Faster code would require some clever optimization to eliminate the (very) redundant counting down by these two lines.

If you simply want the count at *one* position, `i`, just call `countChunks(i)`.

Comment: is there maybe a way to paralelise this?