# R: Alternative to for-loop possible?

Tags: r, apply

I have a data.frame with two columns indicating the start and the end-date of a certain event, something like this:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 14260 14317
[2,] 13515 13694
[3,] 13696 13878
[4,] 13879 14060
[5,] 14061 14243
[6,] 14244 14426
```

I'd like to obtain a vector, containing per day (in a period from the minimum until the maximum date in this data.frame) the number of events occurring on that day.

I guess a for-loop would be a logical way to solve this issue:
For every two elements in a certain row, I increase the value of a pre-defined vector containing the current count of events per day with one (obviously only taking the days between [,2] and [,1] into account)

However I'd like to find a code that is more efficient to run in R, I tried to mess around with the apply-function for quite some time now but can't seem to find a feasible way to do so..

In the end, I hope to find something like this:

```
x = [1,1,..., 2,2,2, ..., 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

with x[1] being the number of events occurring on the first day that is analyzed 
(day 13515 when considering the example above)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at rolling joins in `data.table` and the function `foverlaps`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257371/2414948) from a related QA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `test` is your dataframe, then

create `all_days` vector with sequence:

```
all_days <- seq( from = min(test[[1]]), to = max(test[[2]]))
```

and count the events for each interval:

```
events_in_days <-
  sapply(all_days, function(x) {
    sum( x >= test[[1]] & x <= test[[2]] )
  })
```

You have your result in `events_in_days`.

Maybe you want to check the `<=` an `>=` conditions (to decide whether to include the last or(and) the first day in the interval (I included both).

To check the number of days with different number of events call `table`:

```
cbind(table(events_in_days))

0    1
1  853
2   58
```

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, this will certainly turn out to be helpful!